# how to run an appimage app stored at a fat32 storage

Tags: bash, execute-command, appimage, posix-compliant

As [appimage](https://appimage.org/) aims to allow portability I was expecting something very similar to the apple .app format ([apple.application-bundle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)#macOS_application_bundles)) .

I don't know how to launch an app from an appimage file stored in a fat32 USB (macOS allows it from its .app format).

Also I don't know how to browse the appimage content. is it possible?

Note1: Apple .app format allows execution with double click over the icon or from terminal launching an executable file contained in the folder structure.

Comment: Did you get here https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/run-appimages.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I provided a link from the official website but here is a demonstration on how to do it either from the desktop GUI or the bash terminal:

Using the Terminal

1. Open a terminal
2. Change to the directory containing the AppImage, e.g., using `cd <my directory>`
3. Make the AppImage executable: `chmod +x my.AppImage`
4. Run the AppImage: `./my.AppImage`

Using the GUI

1. Open your file manager and browse to the location of the AppImage
2. Right-click on the AppImage and click the ‘Properties’ entry
3. Switch to the Permissions tab and
4. Click the ‘Allow executing file as program’ checkbox if you are using a Nautilus-based file manager (Files, Nemo, Caja), or click the ‘Is executable’ checkbox if you are using Dolphin, or change the ‘Execute’ drop down list to ‘Anyone’ if you are using PCManFM
5. Close the dialog
6. Double-click on the AppImage file to run

[image: Source: https://docs.appimage.org/introduction/quickstart.html#ref-how-to-run-appimage]

https://docs.appimage.org/introduction/quickstart.html#ref-how-to-run-appimage

Comment: As far as I know FAT32 doesn't have permissions, so you cannot apply chmod to a file stored in a FAT32 partition

Comment: Ok, I missed that one @DanielPerez and if you know this then move the app so go can install?

Comment: thanks @george-udosen, maybe it is just a problem of expectations. I was expecting a behavior similar than MacOSX, which allows to execution of a bash script stored in a fat32.